# Associating words and their translations - storage options

Tags: javascript, jquery, data-structures

I'd like to store vocab words and their translations in some sort of associative way...

I was thinking in an associative array... each object is a word and its translation.

```
var holder = [];
holder.push({"chinese" : "Nǐ", "english" : "you"}, {"chinese" : "Wo", "english" : "I"}, etc...);
```

Then display the translation of the text you've hovered over:

```
$("#npc_dialog_dictionary_chinese span").on("mouseover", function() {
    var word = $(this).text();
    $("#currentWord").text(parseHoveredText(word));
}).on("mouseout", function() {
    $("#currentWord").empty();
});
```

Which calls:

```
function parseHoveredText(word) {
  for (obj in holder) {
    if (word == holder[obj]["ch"]) {
        return holder[obj]["en"];
    }
}
return "";
}
```

It works: (you can see that hovering over `Ni` displays correct translation `You`

[image]

**But my question is...**

Is storing the translation pair for each word in an object, and then array like so a good choice?

It's only for **ONE** language, but I'll have several different words that will need translations.

Comment: How many words do you have?

Comment: You can run into issues when a word can't be directly matched to another as in they don't directly translate.

Comment: @JonnySooter How so? For this application, I'll be directly in charge of matching each word to a translation. What does that have to do with the way I store the word and translation?

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of issues to consider (how many words, how many languages do you plan to support, what storage requirements, what run-time requirements).

Have you thought of a string hashtable that hashes your word into a vector that stores translated words. For instance, "Ni" could hash into a vector that stores its english, spanish, italian translation. This approach might also scale very well.

Comment: Aren't I already using a "hash table" by using an associative array above? Can you give an example of what you mean?

Comment: While an associative array is a hash table, all hash tables are not associate arrays. Without learning more about the specifications of your particular problem, it is very hard to suggest an optimal approach since, as you might be well aware, problem size matters a lot.